timer does not cancel
When the setHideOrNot function is called I cancel the timer but it still runs after 1 second. I have tried many solutions on the internet but for some reason I can't solve the problem.
  @override
  void addPressedToText(String pressedText)  {
    if (authKeyboardInputController.text.length < 8) {
      String text = _authController.keyboardInputValue;
      _authController.keyboardInputValue =
          text + pressedText; // actual text value
      if (_authController.isObscured) {
        // the text will be shown obscured to user if chars needs to be hidden unless it is latest char in the text
        authKeyboardInputController.text =
            _mainController.makeTextObscure(text: text) + pressedText;
        _timer?.cancel(); // Önceki timer'ı iptal et
        _timer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          authKeyboardInputController.text = _mainController.makeTextObscure(
              text: authKeyboardInputController.text);
        });
      } else {
        authKeyboardInputController.text = _authController.keyboardInputValue;
      }
      setCursorPosition();
    }
  }

  void setHideOrNot()  {
    _timer?.cancel();
    if (_authController.isObscured) {
      authKeyboardInputController.text = _mainController.makeTextObscure(
          text: _authController.keyboardInputValue);
    } else {
      authKeyboardInputController.text = _authController.keyboardInputValue;
    }
  }



lacks the context, will ned full context where it is used, where is _timer object created and stored and etc.

Also, did not get the exact, case you are saying that timer runs after 1 second, does it mean it runs for 1 second after canceling it and than stoping or it just continues to run ?
